# Is there any reason to use a function with a void return over an Action in C#?

Tags: c#, function, delegates, action

Save for tradition, is there a reason why I would want to use

```
void foo(int k) {
    // stuff
}
```

over

```
Action<int> foo = new Action 
    ((k) => { 
        // stuff
    });
```

More generally, are there any practical advantages to defining my functions normally instead of defining them as delegates?

Comment: you mean aside from the saner syntax and the fact that it will be an function instead of an delegate with overhead? No ...

Comment: According to Jon Skeet delegates can be faster, at least when using the method as the target of a callback.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2082735/performance-of-calling-delegates-vs-methods

Comment: as interface-methods ... also: *so what*? - You think it's a good idea to take in the bad javascript parts into C#?

Comment: There are a couple perf considerations. Creating a delegate is an additional allocation. Another is that delegate invocations can't be inlined effectively.

Comment: Syntax and overhead are two separate arguments.  I don't see the overhead aspect as being at all relevant 99.999% of the time (whether slightly slower or slightly faster, it should usually not matter).  I agree with you on the syntax aspect.

Comment: @mikez What do you mean that they can't be in lined effectively?

Comment: Another performance consideration would be lifetime extension of any variables captured by the delegate (also another class is allocated to hoist the variables apart from the delegate itself).

Comment: @Damien If foo is a method when it is invoked the JIT can decide to inline the machine code into the caller. If foo is a delegate it can't really do that because it doesn't know what is being called until it looks up whatever methods (yes, methods because a delegate has an invocation list) were being pointed to.

Comment: @Damien See [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericgu/archive/2004/03/19/92911.aspx) for a discussion of the effect of indirection (virtual/interface/delegate dispatch) on inlining.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, there are plenty of good reasons. The first three to come to mind:

Pretty much any C# programmer will be highly surprised by your extremely uncommon overuse of delegates.

Functions can be `virtual`, and can be used to implement interfaces.

Variables, even variables of delegate type, can be re-assigned, which would lead to highly unexpected behaviour.

But there are plenty more.

Eric Lippert mentions in a comment that functions can be overloaded, variables cannot.

Methods can be implemented as iterators (using the `yield` keyword), anonymous functions cannot.

Some special methods can be called implicitly: `new T { a, b, c }` looks for a method named `Add`, not a variable named `Add`.

The predefined delegate types do not allow you to use `ref` or `out` parameters.

The predefined delegate types do not allow you to add attributes to the return type or parameters.