# Calling "Form" class method from "A" class without adding a reference to the "Form" class

Tags: c#, winforms, methods, class-library

I have two Projects one is  a **Winform**  application another is a **Class library**. I have added a reference to the class Library in Winform and called a method  of the class library. Now I want  to call a different method in winform application from class library but I can't add a reference to winform to the class library.

IN CODE:-

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            A obj = new A();
            obj.foo();
        }
        public string Test(par)
        {
            //to_stuff
        }


    }
```

and in Class library

```
 class A
    {
        public void foo()
        {
            //Do_stuff
            //...

            Test(Par);

            //Do...

        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to re-design it then.  If you can provide a compelling example as to why you might need to do this, perhaps we can suggest a different way of approaching it.  As it stands, your question is too vague.

Comment: The only way is to create a contract assembly, define an interface in it, implement this interface by the form and pass a reference of this interface to the library. Both of your current assemblies could reference this contract assembly.

Comment: Yup. You're trying to create a circular reference (and a circular dependency in general), which is a terrible idea. Don't do it. Why *would* you ever need to call anything from the winforms project in your class library?

Comment: @Verarind, that is one way, but it's not the only way, eg see my answer.

Comment: @DavidArno: Yes you're right. Your solution is an also possible way. But we both did the same mistake. The title says that he want's to call `Test(..)` WITHOUT adding a reference to class A. Hopefully he only tries to avoid a reference to the library. A class reference might be okay.

Comment: @Verarind, good point, the title made no sense as it was the complete opposite of the code. I've fixed the title therefore.

Comment: You could define an event in the class "A" and then subscribe the form to this event. Then just raise the event and call whatever you want in the form class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this by injecting `Test` into `class A`.

For example:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        A obj = new A();
        obj.foo(Test);
    }

    public string Test(string par)
    {
        //to_stuff
    }
}

class A
{
    public void foo(Func<string, string> callback)
        //Do_stuff
        //...

        if (callback != null)
        {
            callback(Par);
        }

        //Do...

    }
}
```

Comment: @too_cool, short answer: no. For a longer answer, please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2082735/performance-of-calling-delegates-vs-methods

Comment: No, calling delegates like this is very fast.

Comment: @DavidArno - Don't forget the `null` check on the callback.

Comment: @Enigmativity, good point. Also I fixed the code as injecting via the constructor was a distraction to the answer of "use a delegate".

Comment: @DavidArno Thx for the help.learned a lot..Just one for doubt can i pass another Form to the Class so that i can access the other form property or methods..and sry for late reply

Comment: @too_cool, you should avoid doing that as much as possible as you can end up tightly coupling the two functions, which will make testing harder. However it is legitimate at times and SchlaWiener's answer explains how to do that: by passing the form to `foo` via an interface reference.

Answer (score 3):

While the callback method from David is a sufficient solution, if your interactions gets more complex, I would use this approach

Create an inteface in your class libary

```
public interface ITester
{
    string Test(string value);
}
```

Rewrite your code so class A expects an ITester interface

```
public class A
{
    public A(ITester tester)
    {
        this.tester = tester;
    }

    public string foo(string value)
    {
        return this.tester.Test(value);
    }        
}
```

Implement your interface in Form1

```
public partial class Form1 : Form, ITester
{
    private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        A obj = new A(this);
        obj.foo("test");
    }

    public string Test(string value)
    {
        //to_stuff
        return value;
    }
}
```