# Calling functions in a loop vs delegates performance?

Tags: c#, events, delegates

I'm developing a game in C#/Unity and I'm wondering if there's a performance boost of using a delegate event instead of iterating over a list of objects and calling on functions.

```
// Which one is more performant?
foreach (Foo foo in someListOfFoo)
{
    foo.Update();
}

// Or...
updateFoos(); // updateFoos is an event
```

Comment: so `updateFoos();` is an `event`?

Comment: Yep, sorry for not making that clear.

Comment: Assuming that handlers on that event are doing exactly the same thing there is basically no difference from a performance point of view - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2082735/performance-of-calling-delegates-vs-methods